# Dynamically changing a texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opencv

I have some (OpenCV) code that generates images. I'm displaying these using OpenGL. When new images are created I run the following function (each time) with the same `texture` name and a new `image`:

```
void loadCVTexture(GLuint& texture, const cv::Mat_<Vec3f>& image){
  if(texture != 0){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, image.cols, image.rows, GL_BGR, GL_FLOAT, image.data);
  } else {
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image.cols, image.rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_FLOAT, image.data);
  }
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
}
```

I initialize the first image *before* `glutMainLoop()` and it displays correctly. It is given the id `1`. When I update the image again the picture does not change. (I have confirmed that the display function is being called, and that the image is different.)

**Edit:** Another clue, I have sub-windows. If I comment-out my other window the code works as expected.

Comment: By the way, `glGetError()` is returning `0`.

Comment: I'm puzzled, that looks *just* right...

Comment: Are z-buffer and color buffer clear when you try to repaint image? Are there stencil operations? glScissor? Or maybe glViewport was set to weird value? What happens when you use glTexImage2d every frame instead of SubImage2D? I think it is related to sub-window code - probably glViewport or glScissors or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works correctly without "sub-windows", my guess would be that you have multiple OpenGL contexts in your application, and that the updating of the texture happens with the wrong context active.

Try putting the texture uploading into your display function and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Correct! Thanks! I have now put `glutSetWindow(leftPanel);` before the call to the above function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to show new images in a sequence instead of the existing ones?
In which case you just need to change the image.data, not create a new texture binding.

Comment: Yes (I updated the question to be a bit more clear). I thought that the array is copied when you call either of these functions. Is that not the case? If so, my image data will definitely go out of scope.

Comment: Assumign they are the same size/format/etc just copy the new pixel data to image.data 

see http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml