# Display cv::Mat with OpenGL in fully native app

Tags: opencv, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to make a simple fully-native app which uses OpenGL-ES. Thanks to the ndk sample native-activity I was able to display a color on the screen.
Now I want to display the content of a `cv::Mat` (capture the camera), putting it in a openGL texture.

Most of the examples involving OpenCV are using half-native app with java handling the display part. Does someone know how to create a `glTexImage2D` from `cv::Mat` in android native code ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading texture for OpenGL with OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126002/loading-texture-for-opengl-with-opencv)

Comment: or [Dynamically changing a texture in OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190719/dynamically-changing-a-texture-in-opengl)

Comment: or [Wrong drawing with OpenCV and OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130962/wrong-drawing-with-opencv-and-opengl)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9098883/743214) for some general considerations when using OpenCV images with OpenGL. Though the question was about `glReadPixels`, the points given apply in the opposite direction, too.